# JQuery addClass destructs styles

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have the following code snipped. It is aimed to add "icon" to the list elements which has child list elements. However, addClass destructs the styles. Even if my ".icon-left" class is empty, when I add this class, my list item structure styles gone:

```
if ($('.brien-sliding-menu ul li').find('ul li').length > 0) {

    $('.brien-sliding-menu > ul > li').addClass('icon-left');

}
```

Following is the html:

```
<nav class="brien-sliding-menu">
    <h3>Menu</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Maps</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Discovery</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And the css class I want to add:

```
.icon-left{ 
    font-size:30px; 
    background:url(../img/icon-left.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Show markup and styles as well, better if into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you try: [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69akn/12/)

```
    $(".brien-sliding-menu ul li:has(li)").find("li").addClass("icon-left");
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work.
I thought that $(this) refers to '.brien-sliding-menu ul li ul li'.
But I want to addClass to '.brien-sliding-menu ul li". 

parent() also did not work and if statement is correct.

Comment: Thanks Aditya, but still not working :(
But the thing is that, your code did not destruct the styles, but it failed to add the css style (please see my updated code)